# Vaadin 10 slot in vaadin-dialog

Tags: html, vaadin, vaadin10

I want to create a reusable dialog in Vaadin 10. Therefore I thought of using the  tag in vaadin-dialog. I created a html file containing the templated vaadin-dialog.

```
<dom-module id="show-sera-dialog">
<template>
    <vaadin-dialog opened="opened">
        <sera-field></sera-field>
        <slot></slot>
    </vaadin-dialog>
<template>
</dom-module>
```

And I try to use it like this.

```
<show-sera-dialog opened="{{showSera}}">
        It worked!
</show-sera-dialog>
```

The dialog will be opened and the sera-field displayed, but the text is never displayed. Is there an error withing these lines? Am I using vaadin-dialog the wrong way?

PS:

It works with this button:

```
<dom-module id="one-shot-button">
<template>
    <vaadin-button on-click="_disable" theme="raised primary" disabled={{disabled}}>
        <slot></slot>
    </vaadin-button>
</template>

<script>
    class OneShotButton extends I18nMixin(Polymer.Element) {
        static get is() {
            return 'one-shot-button'
        }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                disabled: {type: Boolean, notify: true}
            }
        }

        _disable() {
            this.disabled = true;
            this.onClick();
        }
    }

    customElements.define(OneShotButton.is, OneShotButton);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are putting a `<slot>` inside a `<template>`. Template means that web component will do whatever it needs when rendering it, e.g.  by creating multiple instances like cells in grid, etc.
In this case `vaadin-dialog` teleports the content to the body, so as it escapes any stacking context. Thus it makes slots not work because they are not in the same DOM hierarchy.

Comment: If I remove <template>, nothing is shown anymore.. I tried to do the same with a button and it worked? Why is that?

Comment: The <vaadin-button> element doesn’t do any trickery with the DOM, like the dialog does. As Manolo said, the dialog moves its content from the original place in the DOM to directly under the <body> element. And to do so you need to use a <template> inside it. It’s really not ideal, but it is the only way to escape any parent stacking contexts (to avoid the dialog from potentially clipping).

Comment: The main problem is that template content, in your case `<slot>` tag is moved away from the `vaadin-dialog` but your slotted element continues in its original  `show-sera-dialog`, obviously there is no slot target in that structure because it was moved.  This is the reason why in `vaadin-dialog` the content needs to be set in a `template` to warn the user that content might not work in traditional way.

Answer (score 2):

One way to create a reusable dialog would be to create a component like this

```
<dom-module id="show-sera-dialog">
    <template>
        <vaadin-dialog opened={{opened}}>
            <template>
                [[text]]
            </template>
        </vaadin-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
        class ShowSeraDialog extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() { return 'show-sera-dialog'; }
            static get properties() { 
                return  { 
                    "text" : String, 
                    "opened" : Boolean
                }
            }
        }

        window.customElements.define(ShowSeraDialog.is, ShowSeraDialog);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

And use it like this

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="./show-sera-dialog.html">

<dom-module id="polymer-test-app">
  <template>
    <show-sera-dialog id="dialog1" text="It worked!"></show-sera-dialog>
    <button on-click="showDialog">Show dialog</button>
  </template>

  <script>
    class PolymerTestApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'polymer-test-app'; }

      showDialog() {
        this.$.dialog1.opened = true;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(PolymerTestApp.is, PolymerTestApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: this works, but just as long, as I don't want to include anything fancier than text.. the text was meant to be a placeholder for more complex stuff as other buttons or pictures